# Checking imageview resource on actionlistener rather than the id of the imageview

Tags: android, image, button, imageview

I have 16 imageview, each set to onBtnClick as a listner, inside this method it checks whether the imageview id corresponds to a specific id, I need to change this so it checks the image resource inside the imageview, e.g.

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v)
{

  if( v.getId() == R.id.img1 )
  {
      Intent guess = new Intent(this, com.Logo_Master.Guesslogo.class);
      guess.putExtra("image","img1");
      startActivity(guess);
  }
}
```

needs to be something like:

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v)
{

  if( v.getId() == R.drawable.img1 )
  {
      Intent guess = new Intent(this, com.Logo_Master.Guesslogo.class);
      guess.putExtra("image","img1");
      startActivity(guess);
  }
}
```

or something similar.....so it checks the image inside the imageview rather than the imageview......

Thank you.

/*EDIT*/

```
Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {

        int v = imageViews[i];
        int next = random.nextInt( 16 );
        if ( !generated.contains( next ) ) {
            generated.add( next );
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( v );
            iv.setImageResource( images[next] );
            Object tag = (Object) new Integer(getImageName(this, String.valueOf(images[next])));
            iv.setTag(tag);
        }
        else {
            i--;
        }
    }

public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
return context.getResources().getIdentifier("id/" + imageName + "guess", null, context.getPackageName());
}


public static int getImageName(Context context, String imageName) 
{
return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName + "guess", null,     context.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tags to achieve this:

When creating your ImageView (in code or in XML), define a tag:

```
android:tag = "tag"
```

OR

```
Object tag = (Object) new Integer(R.drawable.img1);
imageView.setTag(tag);
```

Then retrieve the tag before you need it by:

```
Object tag = imageView.getTag();
int drawableId = Integer.parseInt(tag.toString());
if( drawableId == R.drawable.img1 ) {
      ....
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but the problem i think with this lies with setting the tag.......the images are not hardcoded so i have tried to set the tag inside the loop.....however with this code, the images do nothing when clicked..... is there a way of inside my original code getting the string of the image resource?

Comment: This code shouldn't be impacting the event behaviour of your ImageView. Can you post more code (the loop where you declare the imageview)?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the loop and the two custom functions

Comment: Please log the value of `getImageName(this, String.valueOf(images[next]))` before you assign it and post the results here.

Comment: ok using the log.i method  --   Log.i("NAME", String.valueOf(getImageName(this, String.valueOf(images[next])))); --  it outputs NAME       0........ so clearly the problem lies there

Comment: I need to set the tag inside that loop im assuming as it can set each individual imageview tag.....

Comment: Ok fixed it.....was simple, Object tag = (Object) new Integer(images[next]); THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly with an imageView.  There is however nothing stopping you from subclassing imageView and adding the required functionality.  For example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MyImageButton extends ImageButton {

private static final String ANDROID_NAME_SPACE = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
private int mDrawableResId = -1;

public MyImageButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mDrawableResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(ANDROID_NAME_SPACE, "src", -1);
}

public MyImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mDrawableResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(ANDROID_NAME_SPACE, "src", -1);
}
@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId){
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    mDrawableResId = resId;
}

public int getDrawableResId(){
    return mDrawableResId;
}
}
```

This catches setting the drawable directly and from XML.

(diclaimer:  I have never tried this however it should do exactly what you want.  The example above does work in the emulator.  If anyone has any opinions on this approach I would love to hear them.)